# How to grep and execute different commands for multiple outputs of a single non terminating command

Tags: bash, grep

I have a `cmd` that does not terminate unless there is an error. This command outputs strings and I want to capture different ones and execute a different command for each of these outputs.

I know how to handle a command for one output (`$str1` - simple string) and one certain command (`$cmd1` - simple `echo` command):

`until cmd | grep -m 1 "$str1"; do; $cmd1; done`

but I want to be able to have the cases for `$str2` do `$cmd2` etc...

Comment: Is `str1` a regular expression or just a string? And is `cmd1` just a simple command?

Comment: UL post is closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
cmd | while read -r line; 
do
    case "$line" in
    str1) echo "do something"
    ;;
    str2) echo "do something else"
    ;;
    *) echo "ignore"
    ;;
    esac; 
done
```

since OP didn't provide any details here is a made up process that generates a stream of strings and exits with error

```
$ (for i in {1..5}; do sleep 1; echo "this is str$i"; done; exit 1) | 
  while read -r line; 
  do     
    case "$line" in     
      *str1*) echo "do something"
      ;;     
      *str2*) echo "do something else"
      ;;     
      *) echo "ignore"
      ;;   
    esac;  
  done
```

generates

```
do something
do something else
ignore
ignore
ignore
```

Comment: only some of the outputs